# Why can't I find a Dolphin?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I've outfitted my little Imperial Courier with some passenger cabins to try out the new-ish passenger missions. I rather enjoy them, and they can be pretty profitable.

So I want to pick up a dedicated passenger ship to make use of the Luxury Cabin options.

An Orca is still pretty far out of my budget, but a Dolphin at around 1 mil I can definitely handle.

The only problem is, I can't find any... I've even used this [tool](https://eddb.io/) which is supposedly supposed to show ships, however every station that said it had a Dolphin (I've checked 4) didn't have it at the time.

Comment: I did a quick google on this... and found the following info... I could post it as an answer, but it's not really detailed. https://roguey.co.uk/elite-dangerous/ships/dolphin/where.html

Comment: Switching from an Open instance to a Private instance might refresh the marketplace for whatever station youre visiting, that used to work for outfitting, not sure if its changed. Never really tried to scum for a ship though, shipyards may work differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience I would recommend checking the [Rougey website](https://roguey.co.uk/elite-dangerous/ships/dolphin/where.html) which was also mentioned by Steven Davison in [his comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308675/why-cant-i-find-a-dolphin#comment437536_308675).

When checking a station make sure you check the ones where the update icon is green. While ships should be available for longer than a day it is possible that something like a civil war or famine stops the sale of ships (and commodities).

Also a thing to consider when buying a ship: **Buy it in Li Yong Rui space** You'll pay 10% less for the ship and any upgrades.  I've just checked the website and there seem to be a few stations that sell it within 50ly of the Lembava system.

**Please note that you need the Horizons addon in order to purchase the ship since it's patch 2.3 exclusive!**

Comment: Removed the previous comments, as they are not relevant to your answer. Thanks for the Mention, however! :)

Comment: Unfortunately that site gives the same system of the last I checked that claims to have a Dolphin, but It was not there either. https://roguey.co.uk/elite-dangerous/universe/hip-20998/louis-de-lacaille-orbital/

Comment: @Rapitor Hmm this is seriously weird... I've found all my ships and components with rougey and never had any problems. Are there any wars/riots going on in the system? Also does the station sell any other ships?

Comment: The station has every other ship listed on that page if you select the shipyard tab... just no dolphin. Is there a faction or merchant rank required or something for them to show up?

Comment: @Rapitor The only other thing that comes to my mind is the Horizons addon. If you don't own it you can't buy the ship since it's patch 2.3 exclusive.

Comment: oh? That's likely it then because I am a vanilla player. Odd that what they decided to make exclusives was that ship, I'm guessing beluga is too then. They could also say that somewhere in-game...